# How to grab the user's device token and attach it to an email as PDF file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, email-attachments

My app has a voting topic and to avoid cheating I'm planing to let the user to vote by email which includes his/her device token so I can find out if the user voted more than one time.  Is there any way to grab the user's device token and attach it to this email as a PDF file for example? if so can anyone  please provide me with a sample code? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this seems to be a really bad idea, sending an email and attaching a file... just ugly. Better open a URL on your voting server including the ID of the device.

You can get the unique ID of the device like

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

or prior to iOS 6 you could use [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID).

Then use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do the voting.

Comment: First I would like to thank you for your answer.I don't have a server and this is the only option I have, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Then you need to get one. Everything else is a waste of time and you will end up with the most annoying app ever.

Comment: I like your idea but it makes my question bigger because I have no idea about having a server or where and how I can approach my voting needs with no cheating , can you please help me with that ? Thanks in advance.